# SQL Email configuration on SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, express, email, ssms, email-notifications

I am trying configure SQL database mail send email Gmail to Gmail but I got:
Message
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2021-04-14T09:21:14). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.).
)

I do not know what I am doing wrong.

---- create the database account ----

```
Use MSDB

go

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_account WHERE  name = 'SQLServer Express') 
  
BEGIN 
    

--CREATE Account [SQLServer Express] 

    
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp 
    
@account_name            = 'SQLServer Express', 
    
@email_address           = 'sangitar23@gmail.com', 
    
@display_name            = 'Audit Partnership', 
    
@replyto_address         = '', 
    
@description             = '', 
    
@mailserver_name         = 'smtp.gmail.com', 
    
@mailserver_type         = 'SMTP', 
    
@port                    = '587', 
    
@username                ='sangitar23@gmail.com', 
    
@password                = 'Atlanta2020!',  
    
@use_default_credentials =  0 , 
    
@enable_ssl              =  1 ; 
  
END --IF EXISTS  account
  


  ------  create the database mail profile -------- 
  
Use MSDB

go

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_profile WHERE  name = 'SQLServer Express Edition')  
 
 BEGIN 
 


  
 --CREATE Profile [SQLServer Express Edition] 
   
 EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp 
     
 @profile_name = 'SQLServer Express Edition', 
     
 
@description  = 'This db mail account is used by SQL Server Express edition.'; 
 
 END --IF EXISTS profile
```

------------ To assign a database mail account to the database mail profile--------

```
Use MSDB

go

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
             
 FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_profileaccount pa 
              
  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmail_profile p ON pa.profile_id = p.profile_id 
              
  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmail_account a ON pa.account_id = a.account_id   
              
WHERE p.name = 'SQLServer Express Edition' 
              
  AND a.name = 'SQLServer Express')  
  
BEGIN 
   

 -- Associate Account [SQLServer Express] to Profile [SQLServer Express Edition] 
   
 EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp 
    
  
@profile_name = 'SQLServer Express Edition', 
     
 @account_name = 'SQLServer Express', 
     

 @sequence_number = 1 ; 
 
 

END
  
 
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
   
 @profile_name = 'SQLServer Express Edition',  
   
 @recipients = 'sangitarai023@gmail.com',  
   
 @body = 'Email notification for Audit Partnership SFTP',  
   
 @subject = ' This email has been sent from SQL Server to notify, client uploaded data on the SFTP cite' ;
```

Comment: Have you gone to your [Google Profile Security](https://myaccount.google.com/security) page and enabled "Less secure app access" or "Third-party access"? By default Gmail SMTP uses an OpenID-style authentication mechanism which isn't supported by the .NET SmtpClient that the database mail queue processor is implemented with. You need to create an application-specific password and use that in your database mail account's `@password` parameter.

Comment: yes that did not work